# SQL: select from multiple tables with multiple keys

Tags: sql, select, where-in

I have three tables

TABLE A

```
| id1 | code |
|-----|------|
| 201 | CLA0 | 
|   3 | CQS2 |
| 393 | WQS1 |
```

TABLE B

```
| id1 | id2 | name |
|-----|-----|------|
| 201 |  44 | pluto|
|   3 | 201 | pippo|
| 393 |  67 | pluto|
| 701 | 444 | pappa|
```

TABLE C

```
| id2 | area |
|-----|------|
|  44 |   5  |
| 201 |   5  |
|  67 |  10  |
| 444 |   1  |
```

All records have one distinct id1 and one distinct id2 (keys).

Record may or may not have code

Record may or may not have area

Area values are 1, 5, and 10

I would like to have this table (full list of records, with id2, name, and code - if available):

```
| id2 | name | code |
|-----|------|------|
|  44 | pippo| CLA0 |
| 201 | pappa|      |
```

i.e. I need to

1) select colums "id2" and "name" from TABLE B

2) if "id2" is the same on A and B, also select "code" from TABLE A. If id2 is not available con TABLE B, then list id2 with null code value

3) show only records for which area = 5

I am unsure about how to proceed because I need to select columns from three tables, and the key I'm interested in is only in two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a regular join and outer join with filtering:

```
select b.id2, b.name, c.code
from b join
     c
     on b.id2 = c.id2 left join
     a
     on b.id1 = c.id1
where c.area = 5;
```

Because there are duplicates in `c`, `exists` is better:

```
select b.id2, b.name, c.code
from c left join
     a
     on b.id1 = c.id1
where exists (select 1 from c where c.id2 = b.id2 and c.area = 5);
```

Comment: The result includes rows for which c.area <> 5. Are you sure you can do "b.id1 = c.id1"? As id1 is available only on tables a and b, not c.

Comment: @user3664452 . . . Both queries have `where c.area = 5`, so I'm not sure how other areas would get in.